# how to pass model as parameter to controller

Tags: php, laravel

i want to pass Product model as a parameter to ProductController, usually i do this by :

`php artisan make:model Model/Product -cr`

then laravel will do the magic for me, but now i created model and controller separately.

i tried to do it like this:

```
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  App\Model\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
       return $product;
    }
```

.

*php artisan route:list*

```
| GET|HEAD  | products/{product}              | products.show              | App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@show                        | api,jwt.auth |
```

.

Router

```
Route::apiResource('/products', "ProductController");
```

.

request

`http://127.0.0.1/products/23?withsomequery=yes`
.

No error in :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data        0 Sep 18 12:30 laravel-2019-09-18.log
```

.

All above code return empty array, yet i know it should return something.

I expected it to return something like:

```
{
 id: 23
 name: computer
 created_at: 2019-02-02
 updated_at: 2019-02-02
}
```

Comment: for a show, you don't need request. the model name is enough to get the data by its id. try to remove the request and do dd($product). tell us after dd what you will get

Comment: I do need it to do other logic that i did not write here because they are not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get all routes of related to this route:

```
php artisan route:list
```

and find `products.show` route to check if you should get $product in controller or not and remove `Request $request` for show()

Edit :

```
Route::apiResource('/products', "ProductController")
->middleware('bindings');
```

bindings exists in kernel.php:

```
'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
```

Comment: there are some query expected, how will i access them without: ```Request $request```?. i have also updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Check first that Product model is included at the top, like

```
use App\Product;
```

also make sure that product id 23 is available in your database.

Check your log file and see if it generates any errors.

Also One thing I have noticed that you created a apiResource if its an api route add /api/ to the endpoint.

Check all your endpoints by the php artisan route:list

Comment: the model is included, because if it was not,i would be getting specific error to that. and i am positive that the record it present it the database. the api end point is not the issue here, i removed the need of specifying the ```/api/``` in requests. lastly there is no error message.

Answer (score 1):

It's Happen when you write a route & unfortunately you add a space.

```
Route::get('/products/{product } ', "ProductController");
```

But here you use apiResource & no space is showing.Please Check all route Carefully,

```
php artisan route::list
```

that any other single **product.show** name route exist or not. 
When you get this after that

```
public function show($id)
    {
       $variable=Product::find($id);
    }
```

Comment: when i use ```Route::get('/products/{product } ', "ProductController");``` it works fine, the problem comes when i use ```apiResource```